# RefreshToken from GoogleDrive sdk from authTOken received

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate GoogleDriveSDK

Here is my code

```
mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(new ConnectionCallbacks() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) 
            {               
                AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(AddAccountActivity.this);
                am.getAuthToken(am.getAccounts()[0], "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE, new Bundle(), AddAccountActivity.this, 
                        new OnTokenAcquired(), null);
            }
        })
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new OnConnectionFailedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) 
            {
                if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) 
                {
                    try {
                            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(AddAccountActivity.this, ACTIVITY_RESULT_GOOGLE);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) 
                        {}
                } 
                else 
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), AddAccountActivity.this, 0).show();
            }
        })
        .build();
        mGoogleClient.connect();

private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> 
    {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) 
        {
            try {
                final String token = result.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);


                Intent launch = (Intent)result.getResult().get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                if (launch != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(launch, 3025);
                    return; // Not sure why... I wrote it here for some reason. Might not actually be necessary.
                }
            } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                // Handle it...
            } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                // Handle it...
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Handle it...
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is,i am not sure how can i get RefreshToken from authToken and save it for later use.

Secondly how can i use this `refreshtoken` saved to `initialise` Drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how much this helps. But you can have a look at this code and see if it helps.
https://github.com/sDurgam/koszt/blob/master/sTestJSONTables/src/com/example/s_expensemanager/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Google drive only returns a refresh token during the initial login exchanging the code for the OAuth token.

> refresh_token (optional)  This field is only present if access_type=offline is included in the authentication request. For details, see Refresh tokens.

See the [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect). This talks about how to us http requests and not the java objects but I would think the objects could be used in the same manor.